# Simplified alternative to QR codes for feature recognition?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image

I'm working on a vision test and would appreciate some insight on modern feature detection on iOS.

The idea is to recognize when a user turns their head 90 degrees to the left and 90 degrees to the right — and then fire an event. This is done while the users is continuously shaking their head — so it needs to be quick.

In my current solution I have two large (5") QR codes on each side of the user's head. I then Core Image's CIDetectorTypeQRCode to detect the QR code and using the messageString to decide if it was the left or right.

This works surprisingly well up to a distance of 1 meter. The end solution needs to work at 3 meters. Further than 1 meter and the little boxes in the QR code get too hard for the front facing camera to read (probably due to blurring as well).

Obviously the QR codes are overkill in the amount of data that needs to be recognized and transmitted — I'm really only interested in a 0 or 1. My thinking was that I could make a very simple QR code or pattern that could be recognized at a longer distance.

Can someone point me to an existing library or approach that would be better suited for quickly recognizing two distinct (but simple) patterns I could put on the user's head?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Why not just a large colored dot?  Red on one side, green on the other, for example.

Comment: @robmayoff — What would be the method of detection?